# Inhabitants of promoted type by DataKinds

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

DataKinds according to [GHC User Guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/data_kinds.html#overview), promotes datatype to a kind and constructors to type constructors.

```
Nat :: Type
'Zero :: Nat
'Succ :: Nat -> Nat
```

Q1. Types are sets of values, but how can I get term-level values of the promoted types?

In ghci, for example, `bottom` is even not inhabitants of type `'Zero'.

```
λ: undefined :: 'Zero

<interactive>:3:14: error:
    • Expected a type, but ‘'Zero’ has kind ‘Nat’
    • In an expression type signature: 'Zero
      In the expression: undefined :: 'Zero
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = undefined :: 'Zero
```

Q2. Is type of kind `Type` the only kind where term-level values can inhabit?

Q3. If there is no inhabitants in the promoted types, does this also mean the promoted types `'Zero' ''Succ' can only be used at type-level?

Comment: [`GHC.Exts.Any :: k`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:Any) can be used for undefined on the type level: `:kind Any :: Zero`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No values inhabit promoted types.
2. Yes, `Type` is the only kind with types inhabited by terms.
3. Yes, `'Zero` and `'Succ` can only be used at the type-level. But I think this is not so interesting an observation; it is also true that, say, `Int` can only be used at the type-level.